# Why does "exec" gives "child exited abnormally" in this code?

Tags: tcl

I am running this code in tcl:-

```
set version [exec grep "INTERNAL VERSION:" mojave.log | sed -n -e "s/INTERNAL VERSION: //g" > xor.diff]

set p [exec diff ../log.warning.diff ../log.warning.gold >> xor.diff ]
```

For the last line it gives the following error after doing some diff:-

```
> RULE-311 WARNING: Gdsii layer number 85 datatype 0 has already been defined
> TCL-11   WARNING: Command "check quartz drc" is overridden, Quality Of
> TCL-11   WARNING: Command "delete marker quartz" is overridden, Quality Of
> TCL-11   WARNING: Command "import marker quartz" is overridden, Quality Of
> TCL-11   WARNING: Command "mojave! run filter log" is overridden, Quality Of
> TCL-11   WARNING: Command "run quartz gui" is overridden, Quality Of Results
> TCL-11   WARNING: Command "ui! mojave draw rectangle" is overridden, Quality
> TCL-11   WARNING: Command "ui! mojave set_context" is overridden, Quality Of
> TCL-12   WARNING: Overridden command "mojave! run filter log" is used,
child process exited abnormally
     while executing
"exec diff ../log.warning.diff ../log.warning.gold 2> xor.diff "
     invoked from within
"set p [exec diff ../log.warning.diff ../log.warning.gold 2> xor.diff ]"
     (file "test.tcl" line 4)
     invoked from within
"source test.tcl"
```

And it is not writing anything in "`xor.diff`" file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exec` returns an error if the command returns non-zero or if it sends anything to stderr. There's a very thorough discussion of using `catch` with `exec` at http://wiki.tcl.tk/exec

Answer (score 4):

`diff` (and `comm`) exits nonzero if any differences are found, so you can redirect the output to use them as "did this change?" tests.  For Tcl you'll want to use the `|| :' idiom to ignore the exit status.

P.S. "useless use of grep"... `sed -n -e '/INTERNAL VERSION: /s//gp'`

Comment: If we write the "exec" command inside "catch" it works. Thanks for help.

Comment: +1 for "useless use of grep"; saved me from answering to that effect